# How to generate a random sequence of random string characters in Python

Tags: python-3.x

In Python, I am attempting to generate a 6-character random chunk of letters and numbers. While I have been able to generate random individual characters and numbers, I am unable to change their sequence with `random.shuffle()`, ending up with something like `abc123` instead of `a1b23c`. Does anyone know how to randomize the sequence of these characters?

My code is written using Pycharm, importing Tkinter to create a window

```
import string
import random
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

A = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
B = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
C = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
D = random.choice(string.digits)
E = random.choice(string.digits)
F = random.choice(string.digits)

x = (A, B, C, D, E, F)
# I need the sequence, or 'x', to be randomized for the Label to display
ScrambledText = Label(root, text=x)
ScrambledText.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've checked other threads, and haven't found a solution to this problem yet

Comment: You want there to be exactly three letters and three numbers? Can you show how you tried `random.shuffle()`?

Comment: Since this question is completely unrelated to tkinter and pycharm, can you please remove those from the tags and the code?

Comment: You don't seem to be *trying* to use `random.shuffle`. Presumably you tried it on that tuple and were told that tuples don't support item assignment - switch to a list `[A, B, C, D, E, F]` instead.

Comment: how do you switch to a list? and yes, you're right @jonrsharpe

Comment: Use the syntax I showed in the comment.

Comment: alright, everything works now, thanks for telling me about list. :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't seem to be trying to use `random.shuffle`. Presumably you tried it on that tuple and were told that tuples don't support item assignment - switch to a list `[A, B, C, D, E, F]` instead. 
– @jonrsharpe